# Opencart could not load model

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module

I am developing my own module for opencart 2.3.0.2 and everything was working fine. I have a model in admin/model/extension/module folder which is called vehicle.php.
I try to load it in the controller like this:

```
$this->load->model('extension/module/vehicle');
```

But it throws Could not load model extension/module/vehicle! exception. And it happened suddenly. The model was loading fine 5 minutes ago. I have no idea why it suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Probably some syntax error? Does you editor have syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 1):

I found it.  It was very stupid mistake: 
I just named my file `verhicle` instead of `vehicle`.

Comment: Easy mistake to make.  Please be sure to mark your answer as correct so people know the problem has been solved.  Who knows - it might help someone else who made the same mistake!